# Java how to get certain word from array

Tags: java

I have an array which stored

```
Array[0] = "Information of student, Class Allocated: 2B (13), Class Opposite: 1B (12)"
Array[1] = "Information of student, Class Allocated: 1B (12), Class Opposite: 2B (13)"
Array[2] = "Information of student, Class Allocated: 1A (10), Class Opposite: 2A (11)"
```

I need the information of **Class Allocated**: and  **Class Opposite**. Whereby  I need to get the 2B and 13 but store in different variable. Which can be

```
For Array[0]
Floor = 2B
ClassNo = 13
Opposite = 1B
OppositeClass = 12
```

Can anyone tell me how to get it? Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: anything that you've tried so far?

Comment: Google "java regular expressions"

Comment: First of all, define your own data model for a line of ``Array``, then provide a method to parse a line to the model, e.g.: http://pastebin.com/H7i8GNg5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of split method in String.

Assuming you have standard format.

```
String [] commasplit = Array[0].split(",");
```

And then

```
String [] allocated = commasplit[1].split(" : ");
String allocatedValue = allocated[1] //2B (13)
```

Given the codes, write a generic method with method params, so that you won't end up in writing it multiple times.

Comment: @new to Java - Split by space :)

Comment: is that possible to split 2B and 13 also? for example
String floor = 2B;
int room = 13

Comment: This should be done by pattern matching, not by simple splits