# How to handing string java

Tags: java, string

I have one string: "xx:yy:zz.ss" or "x:y:zz.ss"I want to cut them out of the chain:

```
string1: "xx"
string2: "yy"
string3: "zz"
string4: "ss"
```

help me

Comment: just answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351463/java-how-to-get-certain-word-from-array/34351488#34351488

Comment: take a look at String.split()

Comment: Why there are down votes,  he is new user, i think you @CaoGiaLuat  should read [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Do splitting. [`string.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) should accept regex as a parameter.

```
string.split("[.:]");
```

Comment: [Link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))